# Why cant i write a data record without foreign-key with a model which contains a nullable foreign-key?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have consulted the django documenation which says if you want a foreign key which can be optional you need the following options to be set on the model: on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, default=None

I dropped the complete database, checked the field in MYSql admin. The field is correctly set to optinally contain NULL values.
Could anyone explain why this is happening or what im doing wrong?

Model:

```py
Model:
class MediaImage(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Image")
        verbose_name_plural = _('Image')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    content = models.FileField(upload_to=person_directory_path, storage=private_storage, verbose_name=_("Image"))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_("Titel"), blank=True)
    classification = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="image")
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("User"))
```

View:

```py
@login_required
def mediafiles_add_image(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
      form = MediafilesAddImage(request.user, request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
          image_file = request.FILES['content']
          if request.POST['person_id']:
            ImageFile = MediaImage(content=image_file, person_id=request.POST['person_id'], title=request.POST['title'], user_id=request.user)
          else:
            ImageFile = MediaImage(content=image_file, title=request.POST['title'], user_id=request.user)
          ImageFile.save()
          return redirect('mediafiles')
  else:
    form = MediafilesAddImage(request.user)    
    return render(request, 'mediafiles/mediafiles_add_image.html', {'form': form})
  return HttpResponseForbidden('Something went wrong.')
```

Form:

```py
class MediafilesAddImage(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = MediaImage
    fields = ('person_id', 'title', 'content')
  #person_id = forms.ChoiceField(label=_('Relation'))
  #content = forms.FileField(label=_('Image'), widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept':'image/*'}))
  #title = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)

  def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MediafilesAddImage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['person_id'].queryset = Person.objects.filter(user_id=user)
    self.fields['person_id'].required = False
```

The error occurs on the line:

```py
ImageFile.save()
```

The record should be normally saved here but im getting error:
AttributeError at /admin/datawarehouse/mediaimage/add/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Full error trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/mediafiles/add/image

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
 'bootstrap4',
 'crispy_forms',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'rest_framework',
 'phonenumber_field',
 'dashboard',
 'datawarehouse',
 'students',
 'appointment',
 'mediafiles',
 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'user_language_middleware.UserLanguageMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Django\vierklang\klangkuppler\mediafiles\views.py" in mediafiles_add_image
  56.           ImageFile.save()

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  718.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  869.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1288.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  1241.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1241.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1240.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in pre_save_val
  1192.         return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
  288.             file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in save
  86.         name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in generate_filename
  303.             filename = self.upload_to(instance, filename)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Django\vierklang\klangkuppler\datawarehouse\models.py" in person_directory_path
  40.     return 'person_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.person_id.id, date, filename)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /mediafiles/add/image
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: You need to show the full traceback. I can't see anywhere you're referencing an `id` attribute.

Comment: Also, show your MediafilesAddImage form. Why don't you use that form to save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `id` from `None` type so, it's throwing an error. So, You can change

```
return 'person_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.person_id.id, date, filename)
```

to

```
if instance.person_id:
    return 'person_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.person_id.id, date, filename)
else:
    return 'person_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format('None', date, filename)
```

It should work.

Comment: Found the error, its a function to extend the file upload path. Thx Anjaneyulu!